# how to convert UTC time to specified format in momentjs in ember helper

Tags: javascript, ember.js, timezone, momentjs, utc

i am working in ember with moment js. this below code convert my local time to UTC format

`{{ utc (moment timeEntry 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ')}}`

and output is like Tue Nov 26 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000.

But i want to display the output like Tue, 26 Nov, 2019.

i tried moment-format for utc time but no luck

Comment: Can you please add some supporting details to your question?  I assume you are using [ember-moment](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-moment), but what is your input value for `timeEntry`?  And when you say "but no luck" with `moment-format`, what specifically did you try?

Answer (score 0):

The `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ` part of the code is what determines the output. You can read up on the other possible outputs [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/).

To get your desired output of Tue, 26 Nov, 2019, you should use `{{ utc (moment timeEntry 'ddd, D MMM, YYYY')}}}`